# Does CSS new 'content-visibility' property interfere with scripts loading behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

The [new CSS property](https://web.dev/content-visibility/) `content-visibility` property looks like a nice tool to increase page loading speed.

I want to add it to my page footer:

```
<footer style="content-visibility: auto;">
  (...)
</footer>
```

As it can be painted later on the screen (it appears below the folder for all my site's pages).

However, my page's footer has **many js libs** that are loaded there via `<script>` tags **inside the footer tag**.

Some scripts are eager loaded, some are deferred and other are loaded asynchronously. (yeah, many scripts, unfortunately).

So my question is:

**Will the `content-visibility` property interfere with script loading in any way?**

or will the scripts load the same way regardless of the CSS property?

Asking here as it's new and looks kind of "magic" to me, and I didn't find much related documentation. Thanks in advance for any insight on this.

Comment: I think that you are mixing rendering and loading. content-visibility will only have an effect on rendering. It would be the same with display: none. But any of these would not have any impact on the element being loaded, or the scripts inside it executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you consider Alohci's answer as incomplete, I'll add my 2 cents, but mostly I can only rephrase that what already been said.

I don't have *Chrome 85*, so I can't test it. But after reading the specs [this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain/) and [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-contain-1/) I think that:

1. > ...but if It was a script that adds a handler to an element, it may be faulty, like `$(selector).click(...)` ?

   Just test it! Try clicking an element with `content-visibility: auto` with JS code while it's still invisible due to being off-screen. I'm sure handler will work. There is nothing in the specs about such matters.
2. > Will the `content-visibility` property interfere with script loading in any way?

   No. There is not a word about resource loading in the specs. But again - test it! Look at the *Network tab*. Script's load sequence shouldn't change.
3. > So, it won't affect scripts that are of general use, like *bootstrap* and such, but **[what] if** it was a script that...

   ...a script that...

   - somehow depends on the size of element with `content-visibility: auto` or it descendants (Alohci already pointed it out)
   - somehow depends on [`innerText`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain/#cv-notes)
   - related to some accessibility features (possibly... not really familiar with these)
   - and in some other cases (read the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain/#cv-notes) if you're interested in the details)
   - and there can be other cases not mentioned in the specs as the feature is still in it's infancy. (And the `content-visibility`'s spec is actually a draft)

   **Yes it can break**

   You can even imaging a script that reads css properties, finds `content-visibility` and throws as it's unknown to it... or even throws just because it's author hates those who use `content-visibility` :)

   But I think that in your case the chances are infinitesimal, as I suppose that non of the scripts you're referring to are interested in your `footer`.

Anyway, any change should be tested (ideally). But also you can never be sure that there are no bugs. So just just try it, if it's worth it, and see how it goes.

Answer (score 7):

It would be `<footer style="content-visibility:auto">` not `<footer content-visibility="auto">`.

It's a CSS property, so it won't affect script *loading*, but because it has the potential to affect the layout, script *execution* could be affected if it, for example, relied on a particular layout based operation such as getting the bounding box of a rectangle.

Comment: Thanks @Alohci, you're right!!!
I've updated the question with the fix, as it isn't the main issue. But your answer also solved the main issue! :) Thanks

Comment: so it wont affect scripts that are of general use, like bootstrap and such, but if It was a script that adds a handler to an element, it may be faulty, like $(selector).click(...) ?